# Ending or dropping an Asp.net Session

Tags: asp.net-session

I'm creating a session to transfering data between asp.net pages. Here is my session create in first page:

```
Session["Data"]=depo.Value;
Response.Redirect("rapor.aspx");
```

I using it with rapor.aspx(second page):

```
TextBox1.Text = Session["Data"].ToString();
```

this process runs perfect.But after I read data from session,I will end(drop) the session,because I don't will occupying the server.I'dont will using timout,I'll ending(droping) the session after user getted the data on second page.is tehere any way to do ending(droping) asp.net session?i.e

`Session["Data"].end` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only remove the key "Data" from your session you can do:

```
Session.Remove("Data");
```

But if you want to completely end the session and delete it's contents, you can do:

```
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

See [How to Kill A Session or Session ID (ASP.NET/C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330268/how-to-kill-a-session-or-session-id-asp-net-c) for more discussion on this topic.

Comment: It depends on what you think 'dropping' means. If dropping means, all the data is gone; then yes in your case it is. However the Session can still be re-used. If you want the server to make a new session entirely, I suggest using the Abandon() + Clear() method.

Comment: I will killing session.As if it has not started.Because I don't will occupying server.

Comment: In that case, use the second option (abandon+clear); as it is the most rigorous. It still can depend on your web server on how abandoned sessions are handled though. But for most cases that will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a session, use

```
Session.Abandon();
```

If you want to remove a specific item from the session use

```
Session.Remove("YourItem");
```

And if you only want to clear a value use

```
Session["YourItem"] = null;
```

Comment: To only remove the stored value in `Session["Data"]`, use `Session["Data"] = null`. Then, the textbox will be empty again.