# Destroying ASP Sessions

Tags: php, session, asp-classic

The project I'm working on is integrating PHP written features / pages into an ASP written site. I'm trying to create a piece of ASP code that destroys ASP sessions when I'm on my PHP pages. I have no prior experience with ASP so forgive me for my ignorance.

So, what I plan to do is to create a simple html link on my PHP pages the points to an ASP page which I want to use to destroy the ASP sessions. I've tried doing the method Session.Abandon, set Session("name") = nothing, and Session("name") = "nothing". Unfortunately, all these methods do not work.

I'm at a lost and I've searched everywhere what could possibly be wrong. Ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Is it a factor that the Sessions are originally created from a VBScript?

Comment: Try `Session.Contents.RemoveAll()`

Comment: oh sorry forgot to mention that.. Tried that too... still won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330268/how-to-kill-a-session-or-session-id-asp-net-c

Comment: I've been there already.. tried all of those things.. unfortunately they generate error when I put ";" after every line of code.

Comment: @JakeTheSnake that's because VBScript does not have ";", it's using a totally different syntax. Either learn VBScript, or write classic ASP with JScript which has syntax more like PHP.

Comment: Instead of `session("name")= "nothing"`, try `session("name")=""`

Comment: How exactly have you verified that the _session_ isn't destroyed with a call to Session.Abandon ?

Comment: @Thomas after the Session.Abandon script I redirect to the ASP pages (homepage). The dashboard is still accessible from there which occurs when there is session.

Comment: can you try to output Session.SessionID to see if it stays the same?

Comment: @Thomas hmmmmmm.... I haven't tried that... I will now thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In classic ASP, use [`Session.Abandon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is the very first solution I tried. Unfortunately still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Interesting, this is the only way I've found that actually does what it's supposed to do, whereas `Remove` and `RemoveAll` has failed me. How busy is your application?

Comment: It should be fairly busy. Is there a reason why that's a factor?

Comment: Not whether it should be, but is it while this method isn't working?  How are you testing this?

Comment: And yes, it is a factor. There's something called Memory Leaks. Where do you think Session data is stored?  That's why people disable Sessions and use cookies instead.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is on the page you want the sessions to be dismissed from use:

```
Session.Contents.RemoveAll()
```

This will instantly clear all session's you have as soon as the page is run

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these are not working because you are not "taking a trip to the server"?
In other words, if you are on a page that has this code:

```
session("s_name_user")="mommy"
session.abandon
print session("s_name_user") 'hahaha
```

Then it will look like session.abandon did not work because the session variable retained its value.
BUT if you do this:

```
session("s_name_user")="mommy"
session.abandon
response.redirect("page2.asp")
```

and page2.asp has this:

```
print session("s_name_user") 'hahaha
```

then we will see the session variable lost its value.
By the way, don't try the "print" command.

Comment: This probably is it. I'd still have to try it though. But, you are spot on, I redirect it back to PHP page. Please standby for upvote :)

Comment: Is it relevant to say that the Sessions are originally created from the VBScript?

Comment: Replace Print with Response.Write perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the content of a specific session, you should use `Session.Contents.Remove("session_name")`. If you want to remove all of the session's contents, you should use `Session.Contents.RemoveAll()`. If you want to remove all the sessions including their content, you should use `Session.Abandon`. Once you removed or added any session, you can run the following code to see all of the active sessions:

```
Response.Write("Total Session: " & Session.Contents.Count & "<hr>")
For Each item in Session.Contents
    Response.Write(item & ": " & Session.Contents(item) & "<br>")
Next
```